# sql to compare two strings in MS access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to compare a series of strings like the following

```
rodeo     rodas
carrot    crate
GLX       GLX 1.1
GLX       glxs
```

the comparision need not be case sensitive
i am trying to write a sql where i am updating the first string with the second string if they match approximately. Here except the second string all the other examples match. I would like to write a query which updates the strings except the second one.

is this possible directly in a query in ACCESS

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than using LIKE, this is not possible directly in a query in MS Access. You will need to implement some sort of [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) function for approximate matches.

Comment: How does this fare in performance?  I've implemented the algorithm in C#, and it appears to be pretty hairy.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot measure the distance of two strings directly in Access. You have to implement a suitable metric which calculates the distance--there are many different ways to calculate it.

Edit: You may want to watch [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metrics) which describes the possibilities very good. The *Levenshtein Distance* Mitch recommends is a very good and simple solution for solving this.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called fuzzy matching and it is quite complicated to code -- refer http://search.cpan.org/dist/String-Approx/Approx.pm

I tried doing this with a combination of SQL and VBA functions and gave up because there were so many exceptions. The best I could come up with in the end was the following:

(1) Used strawberry perl to connect to the ms-access db using the win32 perl module;

(2) Ran sql queries from perl to obtain the two connection  strings;

(3) Used perl's String::Approx module to do the fuzzy string comparison -- this returns 1 for a perfect match and a decreasing number less than 1 for an imperfect match.

(4) Appended the fuzzy match number back into ms-access via a sql query.